# Hit incoming missile (simple projectile missile) in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, game-engine, game-physics

I want to make Surface to Air Missile System in unity3D that could predict the incoming missile position after time 't' and set its interceptor missile angle and position in 3D coordinates so that it could hit incoming missile. I am using following function to get prediction of incoming missile.

```
    void UpdateTrajectory(Vector3 initialPosition, Vector3 initialVelocity, Vector3 gravity)
{
    int numSteps = 500; 
    float timeDelta = 1.0f / initialVelocity.magnitude; 

    LineRenderer lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(numSteps);

    Vector3 position = initialPosition;
    Vector3 velocity = initialVelocity;
    for (int i = 0; i < numSteps; ++i)
    {
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, position);


        position += velocity * timeDelta + 0.5f * gravity * timeDelta * timeDelta;
        velocity += gravity * timeDelta;
    }
}
```

I am using line renderer to get visual trajectory display.
Now I can hit missile only at few position means I :P have to adjust manually. my SAM Missile System set its angle properly but it can't set exact time and velocity so it could hit missile.

Answer (score 2):

You need something professional: exponential curve fitting.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html
http://mste.illinois.edu/malcz/ExpFit/FIRST.html

[image: http://www.ni.com/cms/images/devzone/tut/image7_20080714213910.JPG]

you get all points as a curve and find the coefficients of curve then extrapolate the next point.
Your algorithm seems a little linear for the whole curve but only true for the latest points and this is not enough.

Alos known as non-linear regression.

Here, another stackexchange answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20271/exponential-curve-fitting-with-a-constant

Comment: this method seems interesting but I can't use this because of performance. I want to use physics because it would requires few iteration.

Comment: You need O(1) , curve fitting is like O(N) for all data but if you use only the latest 20-30 points then it is like O(1) for big number of points but yes this will consume a lot of memory and memory bandwidth. Maybe for last 5 points? How many missiles at the same time maximum?

Comment: Right now I am just testing with single missile at a time. later on I ll add few more. I can easily get the predicted position of incoming missile after time interval let say 3 sec. but don't know which angle with which initial velocity under the gravitation acceleration of -9.81, I could hit that incoming missile!

Comment: There is acceleration for at least one of the dimensions so you need to extrapolate for that dimension or you can just randomize the angle so a fraction of the missiles hit the target :)